# Get ID value from html string

Tags: c#

I grabbed outlook's appointment description and got this string:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  ID: 123456<br>
  Comments: blah blah
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get ID value 123456 and Comments value out with c# code. I can only use standard .NET library, that is, I can't use html agility pack. I did something like this:

```
var index = html.IndexOf("ID");
var IDindex = index + "ID".Length + 2 ;
var IDvalue = html.Substring( IDIndex,6);
```

But I like to do something more robust to handle for example ID length change.

Comment: You could definitely write a regular expression to extract it.

Comment: A more robust solution is to use Html Agility Pack or some other library that is specifically designed to parse HTML.

Comment: @ameer Obvious troll re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ?

Comment: @crashmstr OP states _I can only use standard .NET library, that is, I can't use html agility pack_

Comment: @Yuck yes, but that is the *robust answer*. Nothing else will be *robust*. Sometimes it is better to change the rules than write fragile code.

Comment: @crashmstr See also: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can%27t

Comment: @Yuck see also: [Kobayashi Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru)

Comment: You're not trying to parse/interpret HTML, you're just trying to extract a value from a string.  Regex is just fine `ID: ([0-9]{1,})\<br\>`

Comment: @Yuck why wouldn't something like `ID:\s*(\d+)` work

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is not recommended, you can get varied results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something with a [regular expression match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx) and checking the 1st captured group of a regex like `ID:\s*(\d+)<br />`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("ID: 12345<br />", @"ID:\s*(\d+)<br />"))
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```